# Magento 2 : Cancel particular order item

Tags: magento

> How can to cancel particular item of an order not complete order in custom module

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for how to cancel a particular item from whole order for that set setQtyCanceled() for a particular order item  :

```
$orderDetail = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load(1);
if ($orderDetail->canCancel()) {
    $orderItems = $orderDetail->getAllItems();        
    foreach ($orderItems as $value) {
        if($value['product_id']==122))
        {    
            $value->setQtyCanceled($value['qty_ordered']);
            $value->save();  
        }
        else
        {
         continue;
        }
    }
    $orderDetail->save();
}
```

Here i want to cancel an order item of order no 1 and whose product id is 122.
This works for me

Comment: Is this solution working fine for multiple items for order. I try this solution for cancel items for order using API but not getting proper result.

Comment: @nidhi, will it restore the revenue reports statistics data as well?